# export a single (.class) file

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, jar

I'm trying to export a single class file (.class) separately from my code in IntelliJ IDEA. I attempted to follow some online advice and the official instructions by going to 'File' > 'Project Structure' > 'Artifacts' > 'Build', but in the collapsed directory, I can only export `.java` files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just need one .class file, you can go to your IdeaProjects folder, where IntelliJ stores its projects, and then open the directory of your project. Then:

1. Click on the "out" directory
2. Click on the "production" directory
3. Click on the file with your project name as its name
4. If you have packages, you should find the correct package, and click on those directories (e.g. if your package is "com.package", you will need to click on the directory "com", and then the directory "package")
5. Find all the .class files in your project.

Please note that you will need to build & run your project before these files will show up.